# Confusion about what a relation is

Tags: relations

I am having trouble understanding what a relation actually is.

The way I understand it is, if $A$ and $B$ are sets, then a relation from $A$ to $B$, $R$, is simply any subset of $A \times B$.

This totally makes sense to me, all we are doing is mapping elements from $A$ to elements of $B$.
So the relation '=' on $\mathbb{R}$ is actually just the subset of $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$.

What confuses me here:

- Does the '=' have anything to do with the relation, or are relations really just sets of tuples? Do we call it the 'rule' of the relation or something along those lines?
- How do I interpret the question: *"How many relations are there on a set of size n?"*. Is it simply the cardinality of the power set of size $n^2$?
- What would I call a relation which is constructed from randomly choosing 2 numbers from $A\times B$ and relating them?

Comment: " if A and B are sets, then a relation from A to B, R, is simply any subset of A×B." CORRECT.

Comment: And yes, $=$ is a binary relation on **every** set: $= \{ (x,x) \mid x \in A \}$.

Comment: An yes, a relation is a set of tuple whatever; thus, if we consider only binary relations on a set of size $n$, we have to consider all subsets of the set of all pairs.